# git-tfs build fails after clone, missing references

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, migration, git-tfs

I have a team services repository that I have successfully cloned using git-tfs, on past migrations I have had to run the nuget command:

```
update-package -reinstall
```

to re-add all the references and get the solution working, my current migration is a much larger project than I have previously worked with and for whatever reason after running the command building still fails with missing references, some of which appear to be telerik among other things.

there are some dll's in a "shared binaries" folder in the solution some of which match the references to telerik and some other stuff, is there a way for visual studio to automatically find and add these references? doing it manually would take hours as the project is enormous.

Comment: Are all these references added by nuget? What's the error message after you run the update package command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to publish all the packages to a local network share or to a package manager such as NuGet. And configure it as a Repository in Visual Studio.

Useful links:

- http://codurance.com/2015/05/04/creating-a-local-nuget-repository/
- https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package

Then enable automatic Package Restore in Visual Studio by going to Package Manager General settings in Visual Studios options:

[image]

Useful link: https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore